# Extracting cells from raster by attribute in ERDAS Imagine

Tags: raster, erdas-imagine, slope, extract, aspect

I have a raster file that gives me the slope of all the hills and mountains in an area in degrees (0-90) and I need to extract all the cells which are  >= 45 with an operator in the model builder.  I have a pretty good idea of how this would work, but what I don't know is what operator will extract this data into a new raster file or mask.  Can anyone give me the name of an operator that does this?

Basically, I need to know what operator is ERDAS Imagine's equivalent to ArcMap's Extract by Attributes tool.